# javascript, for-of in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript

i'm probably missing something about js array.

given this array:

```
let a = []
```

i add two more array

```
a["b"] = [1,2,3]
a["c"] = [4,5,6]
```

why its lenght is 0 ?

```
a.length
0
```

why i can't for-of?

```
for (const val of a) { console.log(val)}
undefined
```

but i can do for the inside array

```
for (const val of a["b"]) { console.log(val)}
1
2
3
```

what is wrong in what i'm doing here?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are generally meant to be collection of *values only*, which can be associated with a *numeric* index (integers starting with 0).

Arrays also happen to be objects, and objects can have arbitrary key-value pairs associated with them by assigning to a property of the object. For similar reasons, you can do this for functions:

```js
function foo() {
}
foo.someProp = 'bar';
console.log(foo.someProp);
```

But, in both cases, this is *pretty weird* and should be avoided unless you're *sure* of what you're doing.

If you want to use an array, assign to numeric indicies of the array, or use `push`:

```js
const a = [];
a.push([1,2,3]);
a.push([4,5,6]);
console.log(a);
console.log(a.length);
```

Using `for..of` on an array will only iterate over array-index property values. The `b` in `a["b"]` is not an array index, so it doesn't show up with `for..of`.

Similarly, the `length` of an array is determined by the number of array indicies that have been filled - if the `[0]` property exists, the length will be 1, If the `[1]` property exists too, the length will be 2 - and so on.

If you need non-numeric integer keys, use an object or Map instead:

```js
const obj = {};
obj.b = [1,2,3]
obj.c = [4,5,6]
console.log(obj);
for (const item of obj.b) {
  console.log(item);
}
```